# Why is the knowledge of the thermodynamical state alone is by no means sufficient for the determination of the dynamical state?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am reading the book "Thermodynamics" by Enrico Fermi. There is a passage that goes like this:

> It is evident from what we have said that the knowledge of the
> thermodynamical state alone is by no means sufficient for the
> determination of the dynamical state. Studying the thermodynamical
> state of a homogeneous fluid of given volume at a given temperature
> (the pressure is then defined by the equation of state), we observe
> that there is an infinite number of states of molecular motion that
> correspond to it.With increasing time, the system exists successively
> in all these dynamical states that correspond to the given
> thermodynamical state. From this point of view we may say that a
> thermodynamical state is the ensemble of all the dynamical states
> through which, as a result of the molecular motion, the system is
> rapidly passing.

Can someone please help me to understand this? In particular, why is the knowledge of the thermodynamical state alone not sufficient for the determination of the dynamical state?

Comment: I think he  is just arguing for the idea of the canonical ensemble (and in general, ensemble), in which, for you to measure the macroscopic thermodynamic properties of the system, you need to consider several configurations (including configurations whose macroscopic properties (e.g. temperature, pressure, etc ...) are different from what you actually measure.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamical state of a (classical) system is a prescription of the position and momentum for each of the constituent particles of the system, while the thermodynamical state of a system is a prescription of the relevant thermodynamical variables like pressure, volume, and temperature.  Fermi is simply observing that an infinity of different dynamical states would give rise to the same $(P,V,T)$.

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping out :)